# Missing icons & text alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi guys I need help with this.

What you can see from the link is a HTML Calendar. When I try to paste the code that the link provided is not same as the design.

The original design look like this:

[image: Original Output]

This is the result that I get:

[image: Result]

The icons `< >` are missing and the `Month` is not aligned with center.

These are the CDNs that I used:

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Also the jQuery as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
```

The function script:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
  function c() {
    p();
    var e = h();
    var r = 0;
    var u = false;
    l.empty();
    while (!u) {
      if (s[r] == e[0].weekday) {
        u = true
      } else {
        l.append('<div class="blank"></div>');
        r++
      }
    }
    for (var c = 0; c < 42 - r; c++) {
      if (c >= e.length) {
        l.append('<div class="blank"></div>')
      } else {
        var v = e[c].day;
        var m = g(new Date(t, n - 1, v)) ? '<div class="today">' : "<div>";
        l.append(m + "" + v + "</div>")
      }
    }
    var y = o[n - 1];
    a.css("background-color", y).find("h1").text(i[n - 1] + " " + t);
    f.find("div").css("color", y);
    l.find(".today").css("background-color", y);
    d()
  }

  function h() {
    var e = [];
    for (var r = 1; r < v(t, n) + 1; r++) {
      e.push({
        day: r,
        weekday: s[m(t, n, r)]
      })
    }
    return e
  }

  function p() {
    f.empty();
    for (var e = 0; e < 7; e++) {
      f.append("<div>" + s[e].substring(0, 3) + "</div>")
    }
  }

  function d() {
    var t;
    var n = $("#calendar").css("width", e + "px");
    n.find(t = "#calendar_weekdays, #calendar_content").css("width", e + "px").find("div").css({
      width: e / 7 + "px",
      height: e / 7 + "px",
      "line-height": e / 7 + "px"
    });
    n.find("#calendar_header").css({
      height: e * (1 / 7) + "px"
    }).find('i[class^="icon-chevron"]').css("line-height", e * (1 / 7) + "px")
  }

  function v(e, t) {
    return (new Date(e, t, 0)).getDate()
  }

  function m(e, t, n) {
    return (new Date(e, t - 1, n)).getDay()
  }

  function g(e) {
    return y(new Date) == y(e)
  }

  function y(e) {
    return e.getFullYear() + "/" + (e.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + e.getDate()
  }

  function b() {
    var e = new Date;
    t = e.getFullYear();
    n = e.getMonth() + 1
  }
  var e = 480;
  var t = 2013;
  var n = 9;
  var r = [];
  var i = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];
  var s = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  var o = ["#16a085", "#1abc9c", "#c0392b", "#27ae60", "#FF6860", "#f39c12",     "#f1c40f", "#e67e22", "#2ecc71", "#e74c3c", "#d35400", "#2c3e50"];
  var u = $("#calendar");
  var a = u.find("#calendar_header");
  var f = u.find("#calendar_weekdays");
  var l = u.find("#calendar_content");
  b();
  c();
  a.find('i[class^="icon-chevron"]').on("click", function() {
    var e = $(this);
    var r = function(e) {
      n = e == "next" ? n + 1 : n - 1;
      if (n < 1) {
        n = 12;
        t--
      } else if (n > 12) {
        n = 1;
        t++
      }
      c()
    };
    if (e.attr("class").indexOf("left") != -1) {
      r("previous")
    } else {
      r("next")
    }
  })
});
</script>
```

Lastly the styling CSS:

```
#calendar {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 320px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#calendar_weekdays div {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

#calendar_content, #calendar_weekdays, #calendar_header {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  z-index: 10;
}

#calendar_weekdays div, #calendar_content div {
  width:40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #787878;
}

#calendar_content {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px; 
  border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
}

#calendar_content div{
  float: left;
}

#calendar_content div:hover {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

#calendar_content div.blank {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

#calendar_header, #calendar_content div.today {
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#calendar_content div.today {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#calendar_header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FF6860;
  padding: 18px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px; 
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
}

#calendar_header h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float:left;
  width:70%;
}

i[class^=icon-chevron] {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  width:15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[Reference Link <](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzMPQZ)

Comment: Here is the link im not allowed to add more than 2 links.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzMPQZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. This is fixed.

I changed all function script that include this,

```
('i[class^="icon-chevron"]')
```

to FontAwesome class, so it would be like this.

```
('i[class^="fa"]')
```

example my class at HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-left">
```

And of course I have to style. Then everything is like the codepen Calendar example.

Answer (score 0):

The previous month / next month arrows are using the [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) font which you aren't including in your document.

Add a reference to the font awesome CSS and font files or add the following link to the CDN version in your HEAD:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I added but still not working yet.  Yes today my class lecturer just teach us the Font Awesome. WEW idk what  is that too confuse but i'm learning hard.

Comment: Have you downloaded the FontAwesome font files and placed them in your project? make sure the path in the CSS file matches the path to your font files.

Comment: Yes I did it. I linked the css without .min (font-awesome)

Answer (score -1):

Turnip is right.

Try to add this to your head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I added but still not working yet.  Yes today my class lecturer just teach us the Font Awesome. WEW idk what  is that too confuse but i'm learning hard.